# PHP script not being run on server from C#

Tags: c#, php, file, server

I have a script on a server that simply writes a file to its directory.

I am interacting with this php script by this code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.myserver.com/myDir/myPhpFile.php");
```

It does not work, the file is not being written.

However, if I go to the `http://www.myserver.com/myDir/myPhpFile.php`website on my chrome browser, the file successfully gets created on the server.

What is this doing that the C# script is not doing?

Note: I have already set all relevant permissions.

EDIT: getting the responses.

```
for (int i = 0; i < request.GetResponse().Headers.Count; i++) {
    Debug.Log (request.GetResponse().Headers.Get (i));
}
```

I got eight responses:

```
text/html
Microsoft-IIS/8.0
ASP.NET
PleskWin
Fri, 05 Dec 2014 10:14:15 GMT
0
keep-alive
261
```

Comment: You have not posted any code that actually makes a request, do you also have code something like `var response = request.GetResponse();`, if so what response is returned?

Comment: @BenRobinson I don't have that code, I'll put it in and see what I get.

Comment: That is likely to be the problem, it means that you are not actualy making a request, you are just creating a `HttpWebRequest` object for that Url.

Comment: @BenRobinson I updated the question, is that how I'm supposed to get the response?

Comment: That is not ideal as `GetResponse()` is what makes the http request to the server so it will make 2 requests per loop iteration. call `GetResponse()` once and store the response in a variable.

Comment: @BenRobinson OH! It's working now. I don't understand, why do I need to ask for a response? I intuitively thought that the response doesnt matter as long as the request was sent.

Comment: Your initial line of code does not make a request, it ismply creates an object capable of making a request. `GetResponse()` actually makes the call, if you don't care about the response then you can discard it, but if you don't call it then no request is ever made.

Comment: I see, that was very informative, post an answer and ill accept. Thanks.